# Using ggplot to plot number of TRUE statements from a df

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a graph where number of TRUE statement from a df column.

I have a df that looks like this

```
Speed   Month_1
12      67
12      114
12      155
12      44
13      77
13      165
13      114
13      177
...
```

And I would like to plot a bargraph where we have x = Speed and y = Number of rows that are above 100 in Month_1 column.

So for X = 12 I would have a bargraph with a Y-value of 2 and for X = 13 I would have a Y-value of 3.

Can I do this directly in ggplot, or do I have to create a new DF first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just filter out the values below 100 in the data you pass to `ggplot` and do a normal `geom_bar`

```r
ggplot(df[df$Month_1 >= 100, ], aes(factor(Speed))) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, fill = 'deepskyblue4')  +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = 'Speed')
```

[image]

If, for some reason, you really need to pass the full data frame without filtering it, you can fill the < 100 values with a fully transparent colour:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(Speed), fill = Month_1 > 100)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5)  +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#00000000', 'deepskyblue4')) +
  labs(x = 'Speed') +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to filter your data frame and then plot it with `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Speed = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13),
             Month_1 = c(67, 114, 155, 44, 77, 165, 114, 177))

df %>% filter(Month_1 > 100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Speed)) + geom_bar()
```